# form API, нет поля для ввода POST запроса

Tags: post, form, django-rest-framework

[image: На этом скрине видно что есть поле для ввода пост запроса API]

На этом скрине видно что есть поле для ввода пост запроса API. Но когда я захожу в swagger что бы потестировать его, то в методах POST, PUT просто нет тела запроса куда можно было бы прописать хоть какие то данные. В итоге приходит ответ о том что я не заполнил обязательные поля в API, а я не пойму куда их нужно прописать именно в swagger. Когда использую ListCreateView, то оно само и в свагере и в панели джанго прописывает даже названия полей, тоесть создает форму. Но когда я самописно описую POST внутри класса APIView, то сталкиваюсь с такой проблемой. Думал что нужно определить форму, но форму можно зарендерить только в HTML документ, что мне явно не подходит так как я пытаюсь написать API. Подскажите как сделать так что бы в swagger появилось поле для ввода данных?